# C++ - Replace int elements of an array with another

Tags: c++, arrays, scope

I've been going through the Fourth Edition of C++ Primer, and I'm on a pointer exercise right now. The exercise asks to make a program to go through an array and replace the elements with 0. I have this so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++)
        arr[i] = 0;
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

> `name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping`

How do I change the element?

Comment: Do not post your code as an image. Post the code as text here. Furthermore, your code lacks details (*which* errors do you get?) – the code, as is, should work.

Comment: How on earth is a link to a picture somewhere else better than code, especially when SO has the ability to integrate code into posts? That aside, I thought this was a pointer exercise. There are no pointers here.

Comment: You might want to post the various errors you're getting.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to format it in the question. But here it is: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    arr[i] = 0;
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
}

Comment: @David, you inserted braces that weren't in the original, that fixes one problem, accidentally.

Comment: And the error is: name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping

Comment: Oh my god, your compiler is ancient and buggy, drop it like it's hot!

Comment: @DanielFischer I know it's bad to assume, but I thought he didn't capture the ending brace in his picture.

Comment: @user1851663, To insert code, paste it in, highlight it, and press the code formatting button.

Comment: @David I wasn't quite sure at the beginning either, but after re-checking the picture carefully, I was sure. OP has posted his code since in a comment.

Comment: @user1851663 Welcome to StackOverflow.  As you've noticed, it's best not to include code as images...and also, be sure to mention the specific errors you get in the text of your question.  We've collaboratively edited it for you :-) but there is an edit button that you can use to refine the question rather than post details in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Hostile, and sorry for poor formatting. I will use the correct formatting in the future.

Comment: I suggest you look into `std::copy`.  The compiler *may* have it more optimized than your `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

your loop should go like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++) {
  arr[i] = 0;
  cout << arr[i] << endl;
}
```

I also recommend you put  `return 0;` before the final `}`.

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe I forgot the braces. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @user1851663 The braces are optional if and only if there's one expressions that comes after it.

Comment: `I also recommend you put return 0; before the final }.` Why? This is completely needless.

Comment: That's true, if you only want to replace the values and don't show them ``for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) arr[i] = 0;`` is enough.

Comment: Well, the braces resolved the problem, so I guess that's what was missing.

Comment: @user1851663: Yes, it was, as at least three people have covered now :)

Comment: @David My preference is to always include the braces--not just because it catches the occasional error, but also because of version control.  There's no good reason why someone modifying the body of an `if` should wind up producing a delta on the line of the condition too, for trivial ping-pong of adding and removing braces.

Comment: Also, common loop termination is to use the `<` operator as in: `for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++)
    arr[i] = 0;
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
```

You forgot `{` and `}`. This means that the line starting `cout` is not presently part of the loop and, thus, `i` is out of scope.

The error is a little misleading because it's focusing on the point that this *used* to be valid, many many many years ago.

But unlike some other languages, block scope is defined by `{` and `}` and not by indentation. Thus, write:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++) {
    arr[i] = 0;
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
}
```

for great success.

Comment: It used to be valid indeed, but if you compiled it with an old compiler, it wouldn't compile the way the author wanted it. The compiler cannot realize from the indentation that the braces are missing (although it would be nice if some warnings were issued based on indentation), and it would compile the last statement once after the loop, which wasn't indended.

Comment: @AlexeyFeldgendler: I don't think anybody's disputing that the OP got his code wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should be like this instead: Remember the 5 elements only go from array indices `0 to 4`!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        arr[i] = 0;
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Change the `!=` to `<` and add the Curly brackets for the `for` loop.

Comment: The `!=` was fine, though for style reasons I would also recommend `<`.

Answer (score -1):

Your for loop is missing it's body. You need curly braces around

```
arr[i] = 0;
cout << arr[i] << endl;
```

so the compiler knows that code is the body of the for loop.

Comment: How does this answer really add anything to the information given in other answers, particularly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13554643/10871073)?